# Use Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I build this laravel query in my controller

```
public function getSpiel(){

        $first = DB::table('Spielplan')
            -> leftjoin('Verein', 'Spielplan.Heimmannschaft', '=', 'Verein.V_ID')
            -> where('Spielplan_ID', '=', $spiel);

        $final = DB::table('Spielplan')
            -> leftjoin('Verein', 'Spielplan.Gastmannschaft', '=', 'Verein.V_ID')
            -> where('Spielplan_ID', '=', $spiel)
            -> union($first)
            -> get();

        return Responds($final);


    }
```

The get() output of this query is like this `[{"Spielplan_ID":1,"V_ID":7,"Name":"SV Werder Bremen","Liga":1},{"Spielplan_ID":1,"V_ID":1,"Name":"FC Bayern M\u00fcnchen","Liga":1}]`
And now, I want to use it in my view in the java script part

```
$.get('/spiel?spieleID=' + spieleID, function(data){
            $('#spiel').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){
                $('#spiel').append('<option value="' + final.Heimmannschaft + '">'+final.Name+'</option>');
            });
        });
```

But what I have don't is not correct and I don't know to use this in my option part. Can anyone say how to use the values from collection in my option java script part?

Think is. This will work

```
$spiel = Input::get('spieleID');
$teamOutput = Spielplan::where('Spielplan_ID', '=', $spiel)->get();
return Response($teamOutput);

$('#spiel').append('<option value="' + valueAusData.Heimmannschaft + '">'+valueAusData.Heimmannschaft+'</option>');
```

This is exactly the same. And this one works and the other one not.

Something wrong in here

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="">Teamauswahl</label>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiel" id="spiel">
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: index.Name will give you the name. You have not declared the variable final

Comment: It is laravel 5.3 and index.Name is not working

Comment: Also what is `Responds()`?

Comment: Responds take the get() output values to 4.get('/spiel.....

Comment: I change Responds to Response . But it will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the logic inside your `$.each` is a bit off

```
$.get('/spiel?spieleID=' + spieleID, function (data) {

    if (data.hasOwnProperty('final')) {

        $('#spiel').empty();

        $.each(data.final, function (index, valueAusData) {
            $('#spiel').append('<option value="' + valueAusData.Heimmannschaft + '">' + valueAusData.Name + '</option>');
        });
    }
});
```

Secondly, change the return statement in your controller method from:

```
return Responds($final);
```

to

```
return compact('final');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing the select box is empty.

Comment: I don't know what do to. I have edit my first question. Maybe more information will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Name` from `value` object

```
$.get('/spiel?spieleID=' + spieleID, function(data){
       $('#spiel').empty();
       $.each(data, function(index, value){
           $('#spiel').append('<option value="' + value.V_ID + '">'+value.Name+'</option>');
       });
 });
```

Take a look at jquery document for more example http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> jQuery.each( array, callback )
>
> array Type: Array The array to iterate over.
>
> callback Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, **Object value** ) The
>   function that will be executed on every object.

Demo

```js
var json = [{"Spielplan_ID":1,"V_ID":7,"Name":"SV Werder Bremen","Liga":1},{"Spielplan_ID":1,"V_ID":1,"Name":"FC Bayern M\u00fcnchen","Liga":1}];
$.each(json, function(index, value){
    $('#spiel').append('<option value="' + value.V_ID + '">'+value.Name+'</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="spiel" id="spiel"></select>
```

Comment: Thank, but this solution is not working. Why? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @HansMuff I've just added the demo script. Please try it out

Comment: Thank you for that. But everything stays empty.